# Assertion error even after initializing char pointer with new

Tags: c++, pointers

Following is my code for String buffer class. I have initialized my `_strbuf` pointer with `new char[length]` in the constructor. Now I want to append it, so I have created a new pointer with `length+1` after first calling `delete [] _strbuf` to avoid a memory leak. Then it is assigned to new pointer of `length+1`.

But it gives an error of `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID`. If I remove `delete[] _strbuf` , it works fine but then there will be a memory leak.

```
StringBuffer::StringBuffer() {
    _strbuf = 0;    // char pointer
    _length = 0;    // integer
}
StringBuffer::StringBuffer(char* newString, int length) {
    _length = length;
    //delete[] _strbuf;
    _strbuf = new char[length];
    _strbuf = newString;
}
StringBuffer::~StringBuffer() {
    delete[] _strbuf;
    _strbuf=0;
}
```

Here is my append function:

```
void StringBuffer::append(char c) {
    _length=_length+1;
    char* newbuf = new char[_length];
    revSmartCopy(newbuf);    // just copying the original string into new string
    delete[] _strbuf;       //commenting out this line and code run fine but memory leaks
    _strbuf=newbuf;
    _strbuf[_length]=c;
    newbuf = 0;
}

StringBuffer::StringBuffer(const StringBuffer& newString) {
if(newString._strbuf)
{
    _strbuf = new char[newString.length()];
    _length = newString.length();
    strncpy(_strbuf,newString._strbuf,_length);
}
else{
    _strbuf = 0;
}

}

StringBuffer& StringBuffer::operator=(const StringBuffer& newString){
if(this ==  &newString)
    return *this;

delete[] _strbuf;
_length = newString._length;

if(newString._strbuf){
    _strbuf = new char[_length];
    strncpy(_strbuf,newString._strbuf,_length);
}
else{
    _strbuf=0;
}

return *this;
```

}

Comment: This is one of the problems: `_strbuf = new char[length]; _strbuf = newString;`

Comment: i have used operator overloading. What i should do to copy that newstring in my _strbuf

Comment: Your assignment operator could have been a simple 4 line function with no calls to `new` or `delete` (using copy / swap).

Comment: By changing your question, you've made it unclear what you are asking. We don't know how you are trying to use the class when it crashes. The obvious problem is in your constructor - as blazs and I have pointed out - but now you're showing a bunch of other code that looks like a bad implementation of std::string and we don't know if you just don't know about std::string or if this is an assignment you're trying to complete.

Comment: @user3585510 First, is this a homework assignment?  If not, use `std::string` and drop using all of this code.  If it is an assignment and you're trying to learn, there are tons of resources showing how to properly put together a string class.  Maybe peruse those examples before making elementary mistakes, as pointed out by blazs?

Comment: What i have to do in my constructor is just copying the string passed as newString to my _strbuf.

Comment: But you're *not* copying it - per my answer, you're simply copying the pointer not the string. `_strbuf = newString` doesn't copy the text.

Comment: You should use `const char *` in that ctor and member initialization syntax in all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
_strbuf = new char[length];
_strbuf = newString;
```

in your constructor; after `new`ing your buffer, you over-write it with the value of `newString`. It looks like what you intended was

```
_strbuf = new char[length];
std::copy(_strbuf, _strbuf + length, newString);
```

(EDIT) or matching the approach you've used elsewhere:

```
_strbuf = new char[length];
strncpy(_strbuf, newString, length);
```

Note, though, that this loses the trailing `'\0'` terminator. It also doesn't check for a length of zero (newBuf will be `nullptr`) or handle newString being a `nullptr`.

-- EDIT --

I would also encourage you to use `nullptr` instead of `0` for pointers if you have access to C++11 (all modern compilers from the last couple of years up)

Comment: It is perfectly valid to delete a null pointer.  No check is necessary.

Comment: I have used copy constructor and assignment overloading . I have edited the above code. Still i need to use std::copy line?

Comment: @user3585510 You can replace `std::copy` with `strncpy`/`strcpy` as you have in your operators. Which pointer do you intend for `_strbuf` to be assigned to in your constructor: `new char[length]` or `newString`? It can't be both, and your current code behaves that way.

Comment: In my constructor , i want to copy the string pass as newString to my _strbuf

Comment: But you're not copying it. You're just overwriting the `_strbuf` pointer and losing the new memory you just allocated. You need to copy the characters into the new buffer.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have used strncpy and it works fine. After implementing this, does i still have any memory leak or dangling pointer

Comment: The code shown doesn't have any other obvious leaks or dangling pointers.

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve this problem is to not rewrite code others have written but worse. Simply use `std::string` instead and this problem will resolve itself.

Comment: I have to implement copied pointer by myself so where should i use std::string? instead of char* _str_buf

Comment: but i have to.. thats my task

Comment: It would be of great help if you could tell me what to do in my constructor to copy the newString to my _strbuf